# Why the system destroys and restarts an Activity when user switches between portrait and landscape modes?

Tags: android

As we know, android destroys and restarts an Activity when the user switches between portrait and landscape modes which we can prevent by overriding the `onConfigurationChanged()` callback. Can any one please explain to me what the actual need for the system to destroy and start the activity? Are there any side effects if I override `onConfigurationChanged()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main purpose of restarting the Activity is because Android needs to change layouts, resources, etc. to adapt to the new screen orientation. As you may know, each orientation (usually) has its own [Application Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html). The designers of Android decided it would be best to simply restart the Activity because so much reworking needs to be done in changing resources.

This is especially important after Honeycomb came out with the appearance of [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)s. Depending on your orientation, you can be displaying a completely different set of Fragments and associated sets of data.

I would strongly recommend against overriding `onConfigurationChanged()`. Instead, read the link HandlerExploit provided in his answer. It shows how to handle orientation changes more efficiently using `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`.

Comment: Yup!.. u r rite Mr.Jmhend. The article was really nice n informational. guys never try to use onConfigurationChanged() until its absolutely needed. Assume that u have many application resources(such as layout files, drawables etc) to b changed on configuration changes. Then better let the system handle dose changes itself at run time. If u use onConfigurationChanged() option, u gotta do all dose stuffs manually.

Answer (score 4):

> While this behavior is really powerful, since your application adapts
>   automatically to the device's configuration at runtime, it is
>   sometimes confusing for new Android developers who wonder why their
>   activity is destroyed and recreated. Facing this "issue," some
>   developers choose to handle configuration changes themselves which is,
>   in my opinion, a short-term solution that will complicate their life
>   when other devices come out or when the application becomes more
>   complex. The automatic resource handling is a very efficient and easy
>   way to adapt your application's user interface to various devices and
>   devices configurations. It sometimes comes at a price though.

Ref: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/faster-screen-orientation-change.html